# Spring Maven rest web service - What is the URL when deploying on real web server?

Tags: spring, maven, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, spring-ws

I followed this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ by creating maven project in intellij, addind pom.xml etc. Then I run on localhost exactly as written in the tutorial and all works:

`http://localhost:8080/greeting`
When `greeting` came from the annotation of method in the controller `@RequestMapping("/greeting")`.

Then I made JAR artifact & deployed it to Tomact on 'real server' (Elastic beanstalk environment running EC2 instance on AWS).

I got from AWS the base URL of my webserver running Tomact. What is now the suffix to my service? This is NOT working:

`http://someEnvironmentName.elasticbeanstalk.com/greeting`

EDIT: How I made the artifact JAR

In intellij I can compile & run maven project and then test it in localhost. So what I did:

1. Right click on the project name->Open Module Settings->Artifacts->Add->Jar
2. Build->Build Artifacts->Selecting the Jar from above

Maybe I need to build WAR? And how to deal with the POM.xml? Now my pom is exactly as in the linked tutorial.

Thanks,

Comment: *I made JAR artifact & deployed it to Tomact*: that's the part you should detail in the question. Applications deployed in Tomcat are war files, not jar files. Tell us precisely how you made the war file, how you named it, how you deployed it.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, please see my edit on the question

Comment: OK. So you didn't actually deploy anything tomcat can understand. Tomcat applications are deployed as war files. Read the spring boot documentation on how to generate a war file: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging, then install tomcat on your own machine and deploy that war file under tomcat. Name it ROOT.war if you want this application to be the root application. Once you can do that, then and only then deploy it somewhere on AWS.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet it works, I added an answer with contribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (Thanks to @JBNizet suggestion):

Follow this link http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

1. Modify the Application.java file
2. Modify the pom.xml (By adding one more dependency)

Then if you are using Intellij IDE under Build->Build Artifacts will be automatically option for WAR file.

Just deploy to AWS elasticbeanstalk instance running EC2 in the usual way. The URL is:

`http://someEnvironmentName.elasticbeanstalk.com/greeting`

Answer (score 1):

If you use spring-boot, you don´t need a tomcat because spring include an embedded tomcat. Only you run the application with Maven. So, the advantage of spring-boot is not dependent on an application server and using other containers such as Docker.

Do you put the port in the call to your webserver?

On the other hand, check your server logs to see if there are any problem.

Comment: My server is AWS elasticbeanstalk instance and it seems it's automatically assign EC2 running Tomact. And to there I deploy the jar.